# Actionscript3: How to Send Querystring Arguments and Parse XML Feed

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

I need to call a REST web service that provides an XML feed of weather conditions.  I have 13 cities for which conditions are needed, and only 3 nodes for each city are required (vs. the entire feed).

My very basic first attempt is as follows:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {

public function Main() {

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
var xmlData:XML = new XML(); 

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML); 

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest
("http://MyUrl?querystringx")); 

function LoadXML(e:Event):void { 
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data); 
Parse(xmlData); 
} 

}
}
```

First, how do I parse the 3 nodes ,  and ?
Next, is there a way to pass a different querystring argument for each of the 13 cities?
Finally, how would I add these values to an FLV that's been imported and placed on stage?  The FLV displays a geographical area and pans from east to west plotting cities as it goes.  At each city plot, the 3 node values need to be "superimposed" onto the FLV.

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **URLRequest** and **URLVariables** and  to pass variable like that

var url:String = "http://MyUrl";
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
            variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";
xmlLoader.load(request);

see [Working with external data](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000316.html) and [URLVariables](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLVariables.html)

Hopes that helps